# Faster screen orientation change for fragments

Tags: android-fragments, android

Android activities have a pair of methods onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()/getLastNonConfigurationInstance() 
for keeping objects expensive for load during configuration changes.

What should be a nice behavior for fragments in such case? 
Is setRetainInstance() a solution? 
What about usage of configuration-specific resources after setting it to true?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to support orientation change, say because you need a different layout, then I have found `setRetainInstance` works for me making use of `onSaveInstanceState` if need be, using the saved state info in`onCreateView` or `onActivityCreated`.

With regard configuration specific resources, these won't be affected by setting `setRetainInstance` you'll still get access to the correct resources for your orientation etc.in `onCreateView` and so forth after an orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to support orientation changes?

If not, you can override this behavior in your AndroidManifest-file.

Comment: yep, I really have and want :)